# "If" conditions in Jenkinsfile pipeline (windows)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

please see below my Jenkinsfile.

Currently I am stopping and deleting windows service, then recreating and restarting.
However I only want to stop service if its already started.....and I only want to delete if it exists.

Can anyone help?

```
node {
      stage('Scm-Checkout'){
          git credentialsId: 'git-creds', url: 'https://jamurphy@bitbucketdev.ca.bestbuy.com/scm/mot/mpx_spring_react.git'
      }
      stage('Build') { 
          bat 'mvn clean package' 
      }
  stage('Create Windows Service'){
          bat 'copy C:\\Jenkins\\workspace\\Build_Mpx_Spring_React\\target\\mpx_spring_react.jar C:\\Jenkins\\workspace\\Build_Mpx_Spring_React\\win_svc'
          bat 'net stop mpxsvc' 
          bat 'sc delete mpxsvc' 
          bat 'C:\\Jenkins\\workspace\\Build_Mpx_Spring_React\\win_svc\\WinSW.NET4.exe install'
          bat 'net start mpxsvc' 
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the when statement as shown below, regarding `mpxsvcisrunning` you can capture the output of the status command and verify it.

```
node{
        stage("stop mpxsvc"){
            when { expression { mpxsvcisrunning() } }
            steps { 
            }
        }
}


def mpxsvcisrunning(){
   // check if the applicaion is runnning 
}
```